# Filter to count number of entities with null value in a specific field in a link-entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

Im creating a diagram in CRM Dynamics that needs to show 2 columns, one which shows number of leads who havent been contacted and one that shows number of leads that has been contacted. The later one works fine, but i cant figure out how to make a filter that counts the null values.

````xml
<fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
    <entity name="lead">
        <attribute name="entitiy1" groupby="true"alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0" />
            <link-entity name="lead" from="leadid" to="leadid" link-type="outer">
               <attribute alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" name="number_of_interactions" aggregate="countcolumn" distinct="true" />
               <filter type="and">
               <filter type="or">
                   <condition attribute="number_of_interactions" operator="eq" value="0"  />
                   <condition attribute="number_of_interactions" operator="null" />
               </filter>
               </filter>
          </link-entity>
          <link-entity name="lead" from="leadid" to="leadid" link-type="outer">
              <attribute alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_13" name="number_of_interactions" aggregate="countcolumn" distinct="true" />    
              <filter type="and">
                  <condition attribute="number_of_interactions" operator="ge" value="1" />
              </filter>
              </link-entity>
   </entity>
</fetch>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain in more detail what your code is trying to do, i.e. why you are creating two link-entities from lead to lead?

Your current code appears to me to be the equivalent of:

```
select l1.entitiy1 = [some aggregate value related to number_of_interactions]
from lead l1
left join lead l2 on l1.leadid = l2.leadid
left join lead l3 on l1.leadid = l3.leadid
where (l2.number_of_interactions is null or l2.number_of_interactions = 0)
and l3.number_of_interactions >= 1
group by l1.entitiy1
```